# Remotely access IP Camera thru Double NAT ISP - would a VPN work?

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding, nat, remote-access, ip-camera

I am dealing with an ISP that provides a double NAT situation to the external port.  The public IP address seen on the WAN of the only router is not what is reported by "What's my IP".
I have tried to purchase a static IP and they don't offer that.
DDNS service does not work as well because of this. As well, external-originating access requests are blocked.  Only outgoing requests allowed.
Located in a rural setting so data limits and transfer rates are low.  100GB/mo without add'l charges or throttling.  Otherwise I would consider a cloud camera like Nest.

I am familiar with port forwarding and address reservation techniques within a router when an ISP will provide a static address to me, but I don't know what to do with this situation.

Someone suggested IPv6 routing but I can't make that work either.  From what I've determined, I still need a static address.

Will a VPN solve this situation?
I cannot expect my client to have a computer running all the time with a Teamviewer window open.

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: I did read that article and it seems to indicate this might solve the problem, but I am not sure.  It is a bit vague as to where the port forwarding is happening.  This is not simply a case of me cascading a router behind the ISP equipment.  They have provided only a modem.  I have to provide a router unless I only want to connect my computer.

Comment: Please look at this service https://tunnelin.com, seems they are using tunneling and can create the tunnel for your case